# How can DecimalFormat more strict?

Tags: java, parsing, number-formatting

There are some related questions on SO but I think this one is actually unique. I'm working on a system where we expect to get decimal input from users in their own locale.

We have a user in Canada who is used to entering numbers in French-style (e.g. 12,5 is a number between 12 and 13) and when they enter that number into our system while in the "French" locale, it gets parsed as a number between 12 and 13. When switching into English and entering "12,5", the number gets parsed as 125, ten times as large as expected.

The problem is that the set of number format symbols being used is different and has bearing on how the parsing is performed. In French, the `,` character causes the parser to switch from parsing the whole-part to parsing the decimal-part. In English, the `,` is an ignoreable "grouping separator".

I'd like to throw an error when an English user enters "12,5" because we only expect commas to occur when there are 3 digits after it without any other markers, end-of-input, etc.

I want to be very strict, here, because I want to remove the ambiguity from a number like "12,5" in English. Was that a fat-finger and it should have been "12.5" or is that a French-language used thinking that they are entering a number between 12 and 13. I'd like to throw an error and make sure that the user is entering exactly the type of input that the software is expecting to parse.

Is there a way to get `DecimalFormat` to do this for me, or do I have to roll my own additional validation?

Comment: Just check the locale and the input string.  It would be nice to throw an error if you detect a decimal point in the French locale as well.

Comment: My current solution builds a regular expression from `DecimalFormatSymbols` appropriate for the locale and does its own strict sanity-check before the parsing.